# Extracting XML data from a file and write to a new file in XML format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I have a bunch of XML files which contain hundreds of reports in each file in XML format like this:

```
<maintag>
<report1>
<value1>Data</value1>
<value2>Data</value2>
<value3>Data</value3>
</report1>
<report2>
<value1>Data</value1>
<value2>Data</value2>
<value3>Data</value3>
</report2>
<report3>
<value1>Data</value1>
<value2>Data</value2>
<value3>Data</value3>
</report3>
.
.
.
.
.
Repeated hundreds of times....
.
.
.
</maintag>
```

I am trying to write a Python script to split these large files in to smaller files which contains n number reports enclosed in `maintag` and write these n number of reports in to a new file. For example, if a file has 20,000 such reports and I want to split them in to 100 reports each, I want 200 files with 100 reports in each file like this:

```
<maintag>
<report1>
<value1>Data</value1>
<value2>Data</value2>
<value3>Data</value3>
</report1>
.
.
.
<report100>
<value1>Data</value1>
<value2>Data</value2>
<value3>Data</value3>
</report100>
</maintag>
```

I have checked many sites and have gone through codes but it is all about extracting data. I have also tried XML splitter programs available but they were not helpful. Is this achievable? I am a beginner in programming and wondering if this is even possible in Python?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does the XML literally have tags like report1 and report100? Could there be gaps - e.g., report1, report3 but no report2? Once you know what the rules are that govern the structure of the XML then it's trivial

Comment: Seems like an easy task for XSLT 2 or 3 with positional grouping and using `xsl:result-document`; XSLT 3 is available for Python using SaxonC, available from Saxonica https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml

Comment: @OldBill, Actually, the report tag names are same. It's like ```<report>``` ```</report>``` and hundreds of reports with same tags...